# Concurrent LRU cache using Lock on key in java

Tags: java, concurrency, key, lru

I am learning about concurrency. In the first implementation below we are using the cache instance for locking and this implementation is thread safe. But when I am locking on the key instance in the second implementation it is not thread safe. Why is this?

**First Implementation**

```
class LRUConcurrentCache<K,V>{
    private final Map<K,V> cache;
    private final int maxEntries;
    public LRUConcurrentCache(final int maxEntries) {
        this.cache = new LinkedHashMap<K,V>(maxEntries, 0.75F, true) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -1236481390177598762L;
            @Override
            protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K,V> eldest){
                return size() > maxEntries;
            }
        };
    }
    //Why we cant lock on the key
    public void put(K key, V value) {
        synchronized(cache) {
            cache.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    //get methode
    public V get(K key) {
        synchronized(cache) {
            return cache.get(key);
        }
    }
```

**Second Implementation (why isn't  the second implementation thread safe?)**

```
class LRUConcurrentCache<K,V>{
    private final Map<K,V> cache;
    private final int maxEntries;
    public LRUConcurrentCache(final int maxEntries) {
        this.cache = new LinkedHashMap<K,V>(maxEntries, 0.75F, true) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -1236481390177598762L;
            @Override
            protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K,V> eldest){
                return size() > maxEntries;
            }
        };
    }
    //Why we cant lock on the key
    public void put(K key, V value) {
        synchronized(key) {
            cache.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    //get methode
    public V get(K key) {
        synchronized(key) {
            return cache.get(key);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is the acceptable outcome? Explain more.

Comment: Hi @ArashKazemi                                                                                                                   currently I am learning concurrency i came across the below example.In Which instead of the synchronizing on the "key" they are synchronizing on the "cache" instance . Assume there are 2 threads 1 is trying to put the key & second is trying to get the different key, In that case 2 threads will get execute sequentially rather than parallel if lock on "cache" instance but when we lock on the "key" both the threads can execute parallelly

Comment: Please edit your question instead to make it clearer what you are asking.

Comment: @rghome  i have updated my question please have a look.

Comment: Reading an entry mutates an internal doubly-linked list to reorder it to the MRU position. This cannot be done under a key lock, as the list modification effects multiple entries. This is why a coarse map-level lock is needed. A different strategy is employed by [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap/wiki/Design), which evolved into [Guava's Cache](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap/blob/wiki/ConcurrentCachingAtGoogle.pdf) and then [Caffeine](http://highscalability.com/blog/2016/1/25/design-of-a-modern-cache.html) (linked design docs).

Answer (score 0):

You have to lock the cache because it is the cache that is being modified by the put operation, not the key.

By locking the cache you are telling the JVM to prevent another thread from attempting to read or modify the map while the put operation is taking place. This is because the put operation can modify all sorts of internal structures in the map. These structures may affect other keys, not just the one you are adding. So you have to lock the whole map.

Locking the key would only exclude another thread that wanted to access the same key. Not only that, but if you had multiple data structures (e.g., more than one map) and you used the key to synchronize on all of these, you would prevent different threads from adding the same key to different structures in parallel, even though they are not related and there is no danger in doing so.

Note that the recommended way of synchronizing the map is to use the `synchronizedMap` method. See below:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads
>   access a linked hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads
>   modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally.
>   This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that
>   naturally encapsulates the map. If no such object exists, the map
>   should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedMap method. This
>   is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized
>   access to the map:
>
> ```
> Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap(...));
> ```

[LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)